# Vue.js getting params from router-link bind

Tags: vue.js, parameters

How can I get the params giving not trough the url but trough a post like params?

```
<router-link v-bind:to="{ 
    path: '/city/'+city.topicID, 
    params: { countryCode: countryCode, city: city } }">

    Chat
</router-link>
```

`this.$route.params` does not seem to work and will on show the topicID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [router-link documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props), it mentions that router-link just passes the contents of the "to" to router.push().

In the [router.push() documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html), it mentions that if you have both a "path" and "params", the params are ignored.  Specifically, it says:

> Note: params are ignored if a path is provided, which is not the case for query, as shown in the example above. Instead, you need to provide the name of the route or manually specify the whole path with any parameter

So, you'll need to use a [named route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) if you wish to use params, and then build your path in the named route definition.